# Rails iterating through model and changing values doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a PiggyBank model where one of the attributes is interest_modifier(format: decimal). I wrote the following method to change the interest_modifier to a random number:

```
  def set_random_interest_modifier(min = 0.5, max = 1)
    self.interest_modifier = rand(min..max).round(2)
    self.save!
  end
```

It works. Now, I want a method which iterates over all PiggyBanks and changes the interest_modifier, so i wrote this:

```
  def self.change_interest_modifiers
    find_each do |pb|
      pb.set_random_interest_modifier
    end
  end
```

It iterates over all records but doesn't change the values. Heres the log

```
[12] pry(main)> PiggyBank.change_interest_modifiers
  PiggyBank Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "piggy_banks".* FROM "piggy_banks"   ORDER BY "piggy_banks"."id" ASC LIMIT 1000
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (1.0ms)  UPDATE "piggy_banks" SET "interest_modifier" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "piggy_banks"."id" = 7  [["interest_modifier", "0.58"], ["updated_at", "2015-06-02 11:53:33.981262"]]
   (3.1ms)  COMMIT
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.7ms)  UPDATE "piggy_banks" SET "interest_modifier" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "piggy_banks"."id" = 8  [["interest_modifier", "0.53"], ["updated_at", "2015-06-02 11:53:33.990404"]]
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.7ms)  UPDATE "piggy_banks" SET "interest_modifier" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "piggy_banks"."id" = 9  [["interest_modifier", "0.78"], ["updated_at", "2015-06-02 11:53:33.994231"]]
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.7ms)  UPDATE "piggy_banks" SET "interest_modifier" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "piggy_banks"."id" = 10  [["interest_modifier", "0.68"], ["updated_at", "2015-06-02 11:53:33.997966"]]
   (0.5ms)  COMMIT
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.7ms)  UPDATE "piggy_banks" SET "interest_modifier" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "piggy_banks"."id" = 11  [["interest_modifier", "0.71"], ["updated_at", "2015-06-02 11:53:34.002414"]]
   (0.5ms)  COMMIT
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  COMMIT
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.5ms)  UPDATE "piggy_banks" SET "interest_modifier" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "piggy_banks"."id" = 13  [["interest_modifier", "0.91"], ["updated_at", "2015-06-02 11:53:34.007100"]]
   (0.5ms)  COMMIT
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.6ms)  UPDATE "piggy_banks" SET "interest_modifier" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "piggy_banks"."id" = 14  [["interest_modifier", "0.96"], ["updated_at", "2015-06-02 11:53:34.010488"]]
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.6ms)  UPDATE "piggy_banks" SET "interest_modifier" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "piggy_banks"."id" = 15  [["interest_modifier", "0.8"], ["updated_at", "2015-06-02 11:53:34.014190"]]
   (0.5ms)  COMMIT
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.6ms)  UPDATE "piggy_banks" SET "interest_modifier" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "piggy_banks"."id" = 16  [["interest_modifier", "0.71"], ["updated_at", "2015-06-02 11:53:34.018658"]]
   (0.5ms)  COMMIT
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.6ms)  UPDATE "piggy_banks" SET "interest_modifier" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "piggy_banks"."id" = 18  [["interest_modifier", "0.67"], ["updated_at", "2015-06-02 11:53:34.023011"]]
   (0.5ms)  COMMIT
=> nil
```

Now, I have no idea why this happens. No errors are raised. Please, help:)

After a few experiments with reloading in console:

```
p = PiggyBank.first
p.interest_modifier.to_s => "0.69"
PiggyBank.change_interest_modifiers
p.interest_modifier.to_s => "0.69"
reload!
p.interest_modifier.to_s => "0.69"
```

But, if i do the following, it works:

```
p = PiggyBank.first
p.interest_modifier.to_s => "0.69"
PiggyBank.change_interest_modifiers
p.interest_modifier.to_s => "0.69"
p.reload
p.interest_modifier.to_s => "0.57"
```

Why would that be?

Comment: interest_modifier has been changed

Comment: It seems to but actually doesn't. It's always the same. I checked manually in the console and wrote spec, both fail.

Comment: reload rails console

Comment: I did that already:)

Comment: according to your logs, data is updated

Comment: `PiggyBank.find(18).interest_modifier` what it gives?

Comment: Please do what I have metioned

Comment: Check my update to the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79414/discussion-between-szymon-borucki-and-user123).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what's happening:

```
p = PiggyBank.first
p.interest_modifier.to_s => "0.69"
```

so we've got an object in memory, p, which we've created and in the act of creation, loaded it's data out of the database.

```
PiggyBank.change_interest_modifiers
```

This will iterate through all of the PiggyBank records, creating an object for each.  These objects are all **different objects** to the one that you made already.  So, effectively, there have been two different objects made from the same record.  The object inside the class method will save the new data to the database, **behind p's back** if you like.

These objects do not have a "live" connection to the database - that is to say, if the database is changed by a different method, the object in memory **does not** magically update itself with the new data.

So, while you have p sitting there, something else has changed the data in the database.  When you say `p.interest_modifier`, you're just accessing an instance variable inside the object, you're not accessing the database.

When you then go on to say

```
p.reload
```

what you are actually doing is something like this:

```
p = PiggyBank.find(p.id)
```

ie, re-setting the contents of the p pointer to point to a new object, created out of the database record.  This object now has the up to date data from the database.

Comment: Exactly, I totally forget about this once in a while:)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the method worked from the start, just forgot to reload the resource :O